# nodemcu can't connect to WEP wifi

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm trying to connect to an unsecured WEP wifi with the following code:

```
wifi.setmode(1)
tmr.stop(1)
tmr.alarm(1,1000,1,function() print(wifi.sta.status()) end)
SSID = "hide your kids hide your wife"
pass = "11111122222244444455555599"

wifi.sta.config(SSID, pass)
wifi.sta.connect()
```

It ends with status "2" meaning wrong password.  I've tried converting the string password to hex and supplying it in hex as a string.

Has anyone had success connecting to a WEP network with NodeMCU?

Comment: Is it unsecured (no password) or secured?

Comment: Also, what version of NodeMCU are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the latest official release (07-04-2015) doesn't seem to work with WEP, you have to build and install the dev branch.  This site is nice for that: http://nodemcu-build.com/

Comment: Most likely it'll also work if you try the master branch. Currently dev is based on SDK 1.4 while master uses SDK 1.5.1.

Comment: It did not work with the master from nodemcu-build.com, maybe the SDK is a lower version there.

Comment: Time flies, what I wrote in February is no longer up-to-date of course. https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/ and https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/dev tell you what the version on master/dev are and https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/releases has sort of a timeline.